# Javascript passing

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image in which I want to be able to point out certain areas and discuss them. 
Imagine a picture of room, rollover the window and text would appear below the picture.

I created a set of rollovers that are placed over the background image. It works fine. The rollover is a CSS pseudo-element (.thisLink:hover).

```
    <div class="thisLink t1" onMouseOver="describe('a1');" onMouseOut="hideMe();"></div>
```

What I want to do is that 
1. when the user rolls over the image 
2. text appears below the image in a div.

I could pass the text from inside the link: onMouseOver="describe('Here's something interesting');" to a function which writes it to the div's innerHTML. But as the description can be long I was thinking of calling a variable:

```
    function describe(txt){
      var a1="aaa ... aaa";
      var a2="bbb ... bbb";

      document.getElementByID('describe').innerHTML=txt;
```

So the mouseover code would be

```
      <div class= ... onMouseOver="describe('a1');" ... >
```

This would send the parameter "a1" and call the variable a1. T text "aaa ... aaa" would then be written to the div.

No such luck. Instead of getting the text I wanted I got the passed parameter "a1" or "a2."

I then tried putting it in an if/else clause:

```
      function describe(txt){
        if (txt=a1){
            document.getElementById('describe').innerHTML="really important stuff";
        } else { ... }


      }
```

Unfortunately that didn't work either. What am I missing here?

// EDITED

Comment: Remove `.style`? `.style` refers to its style attibute.

Comment: whoops. my mistake. It shouldn't be there. It's not in the code. Just checked. :-)   Just edited my example. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to achieve this using javascript? The only reason I can think of to use that is if you would to load the content for the div using an ajax call when the image is hovered. But since I don't see anything like that in your code I'd say to go for simplicity and use CSS.

HTML

```
<div id="hover">Test message</div>
<div id="image"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
#hover {
    display: none; }

#image:hover + #hover {
    display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGCqk/

EDIT:

If you want still want to use javascript, the code posted won't function since the parameter you send when calling the function (a1) is not defined in the function's parameters (txt). I am not an expert in javascript, but try more in the range of:

```
function describe(v) {

    if (v == "imgA") {
        var newTEXT = "sometext1";
            var divIMG  = "div1"; // the div the content should be placed in
    } else if (v == "imgB") {
        var newTEXT = "sometext2";
            var divIMG  = "div2";
    }

document.getElementById(divIMG).innerHTML = newTEXT;
};
```

And in your HTML:

```
onMouseOver="describe('imgA')"  // or imgB etc.
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's not quite what I was looking for. I made a quick update to your jsfiddle demo - and it shows what I'm trying to do. The rollover divs should bring up their own text. Thx again.

Comment: oh. first time I used jsfiddle. I made updates to your site and "walked" away.  Guess that didn't work too well. I just got a login. I'll do it again and post the link. Thx.

Comment: OK. You have to press the "update" button to get a different URL.

Comment: Thx. That javascript you came up worked great. I'll have to see what I did wrong. I did everything except "var divIMG." Will work on it.